# How to redirect Dtrace output when using the -c flag?

Tags: unix, pipe, dtrace

How can I redirect only Dtrace's output when running a script with the -C flag?

like in this case:

```
dscript.d -s myscript.d -c date
```

**Note:** I found the answer to my question before posting it, but I'm putting it here so it's part of SO.

Answer (score 4):

One solution with pipes is:

```
dtrace -o /dev/fd/3 -s dscript.d -c date 3>&1 1>out 2>err
```

which says:

- dtrace's stdout goes to fd 3, which is dup'd from the current stdout
- dtrace's stderr goes to 'err'
- date's stdout is modified to 'out'
- date's stderr is modified to 'err'

Or the more simpler method is to do:

```
dtrace -o log.txt -s dscript.d -c date
```